# ReUse in a ListView inside a ListView (or and adapter inside an adapter)

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, scrollview, baseadapter

I have heard in stackover that it is possible to put a listview inside a listview or a listview inside a scrollview and therefore an adapter inside an adapter . The inner scrollable element will lose the scroll property.
But What about reuse?
If it is a listview inside a listview and both have their own listadapter or a derived base... do they both are able to reuse their own items? or just one of them?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:text="Artists"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:text="Albums"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:text="Tracks"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:text="Playlists"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you can use expandable list list for this kind of approach.

Comment: Nested scrolls of the same orientation is an anti pattern! Please don't do that!

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you need is implemented by commonsguy's `Mergeadapter`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge.

This takes `Adapters` and `Views` and displays them as one merged `Listview`.

> MergeAdapter accepts a mix of Adapters and Views and presents them as
>   one contiguous whole to whatever ListView it is poured into. This is
>   good for cases where you have multiple data sources, or if you have a
>   handful of ordinary Views to mix in with lists of data, or the like.
>
> Simply create a MergeAdapter and call addAdapter(), addView(), or
>   addViews() (latter accepting a List), then attach your adapter
>   to the ListView.
>
> There is also MergeSpinnerAdapter for use with Spinner widgets.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://dannysu.com/2015/10/11/list-in-list-in-list/) is which I've chosen for my case, that I need a horizontal `RecyclerView` inside my `ListView`.

The idea is to treat the inner view (e.g.`RecyclerView`) as one of your `ListView` items:

- create your RecyclerView in ViewHolder
- `findViewById()` & set its `LinearLayoutManager` in `getView()`, `if (convertView == null)`
- set RecyclerView's Adapter in `getView()`
- control your `RecyclerView` in its adapter.

Hope it helps you.